# IBInspectable not working when accessing color information from other class

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I have ThemeManager in my app. And i have a custom UIView which has a colorName InspectableProperty type string. I set colorName in storyboard, the value will in form like "headerbarcolor" or "buttonbackgroundcolor" etc. Now I have a dictionary(in ThemeManager) for these keys with their values in hex format and also have a UIColor extension that converts hex format to proper UIColor.

So I want to pass key to theme manager and it will return me a UIColor instance.
Changes in storyboard are not reflecting at design time when accessing from ThemeManager. WOrking fine when using UIColor or UIColor extension to get color from hex value.

I tried many solutions like cleaning, quitting, refresh all views. but nothing works when uses ThemeManager

Comment: What is *"ThemeManager"*?

Comment: Theme manager is my custom class. I have red, blue, green and default themes which contains different colors. So color for background in red theme will be different, green theme background color will be different and so on.

Comment: OK - tough to say, without knowing what's going on with your other code. I'd suggest doing a search for `using custom colors with "IBInspectable"` ... seems there are a number of articles that may help you out.